# Get specific row information within a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

straight to the point I have a table that is generated based off the rows in database, so what I am trying to achieve is on each row there is a delete button, I want to be able to get specific column information based on the row.

I want something like this

```
function deletebutton() {
get the column "question" value, based on row.
}
```

Below is the function that generates the row

```
function vq() {
   var out = ''; 
   fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=viewquestion', {
       method: 'GET',
    })
   .then(function(response) {
        response.json().then( async function(data) {
            var id = await currentloginid();
            console.log(id);
            data.forEach(row => {
                if(row.loginid == id) {
                    deletequestion = '';
                } else {
                    deletequestion = '<button class="deletequestion" onclick="dq()">Delete Question</button>';
                }
                out += '<tr><td>' + row.question +
                '</td><td>' + row.timestamp +
                '</td><td>' + row.catagories +
                '</td><td>' + row.answer +
                '</td><td>' + deletequestion +
                '</td></tr>';
            });
            queue.innerHTML = out;
        })
    });
}
```

The table

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Yeah Nah</td>
      <td>2020-09-14 12:48:50</td>
      <td>project3</td>
      <td>hey matt, the answer is blah blah</td>
      <td><button class="deletequestion" onclick="dq()">Delete Question</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Another Question</td>
      <td>2020-09-14 13:27:11</td>
      <td>ux1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><button class="deletequestion" onclick="dq()">Delete Question</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Another Test</td>
      <td>2020-09-29 09:26:54</td>
      <td>project1</td>
      <td>Not Answered</td>
      <td><button class="deletequestion" onclick="dq()">Delete Question</button></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` and create a snippet. Assuming the fetch works, please create a [mcve] using an example object - no need for us to debug a working fetchj

Comment: @mplungjan ok, the fetch works fine but yeah I'll make an example

Comment: Please see my combined example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.  A simple one would be to add `this` into the dq function call.  This passes a reference to the button that has been clicked to the dq function, which can then just find the `tr` tag it is in.

Something like:

```js
function dq(b) {
  // first parentNode is TD, second is TR
  b.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td><button onclick="dq(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td><button onclick="dq(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td><button onclick="dq(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td><button onclick="dq(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td><button onclick="dq(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td><button onclick="dq(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I highly recommend not to use inline event  handlers. See my answer for a more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

1. I would map the HTML (I changed the spelling of `catagories` to `categories`)
2. Delegate the click to the container to avoid inline event handlers

```js
const id = "";
const data = [{ "question": "Yeah Nah", "timestamp": "2020-09-14 12:48:50", "categories": "project3", "answer": "hey matt, the answer is blah blah", }, { "question": "Another Question", "timestamp": "2020-09-14 13:27:11", "categories": "ux1", "answer": "", }, { "question": "Another Test", "timestamp": "2020-09-29 09:26:54", "categories": "project1", "answer": "Not Answered" }] 

document.getElementById("tb1").innerHTML = data.map(row => {
  return `<tr>
        <td>${row.question}</td>
        <td>${row.timestamp}</td>
        <td>${row.categories}</td>
        <td>${row.answer}</td>
        <td>${row.loginid === id ? '' : '<button class="deletequestion">Delete Question</button>'}</td>
      </tr>`
}).join("");

// delegate

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("tb1").addEventListener("click", e => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("deletequestion")) {
      tgt.closest("tr").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tb1"></tbody>
</table>
```